# What is the "natural homomorphism" in the definition of an *essential manifold*?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

The following definition of "essential manifold" is in this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_manifold):

> A closed $n$-manifold $M$ is called essential if its fundamental class $[M]$ defines a nonzero element in the homology of its fundamental group $\pi$, or more precisely in the homology of the corresponding Eilenberg–MacLane space $K(\pi, 1)$, via the natural homomorphism
> $$\displaystyle H_{n}(M) \to H_{n}(K(\pi ,1)).$$
> Here the fundamental class is taken in homology with integer coefficients if the manifold is orientable, and in coefficients modulo $2$, otherwise.

**My question is**: what is this "natural homomorphism" in the definition?

**Added:**

In the original paper of Gromov (Gromov, M.: "Filling Riemannian manifolds," J. Diff. Geom. 18 (1983), 1–147.), he defines an essential manifold apparently in a different way:

[image: Gromov's paper]

He takes $K$ to be an arbitrary $K(\pi, 1)$ or $\pi = \pi_1(M,m)$?
**Question**: are both definitions equivalent?

Comment: For any (sufficiently nice) space $X$ it has a universal covering space $\tilde{X} \to X$ which is a principal $\pi = \pi_1(X)$-bundle and is classified by a (homotopy class of a) map $c\colon X \to B\pi \simeq K(\pi, 1)$. Maybe in the case that $M$ is an $n$-manifold they mean the homomorphism $H_n(c)$.

Comment: For your second question, if $f\colon V \to K$ is a map to some aspherical space then it factors up to homotopy as $V \to K(\pi_1(V), 1) \to K$ (where the first map is the map that Moishe describes), so if the composition produces a non-zero element in homology then the first map must as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will address your second question, to show that these two definitions are equivalent. One direction is automatic since $K(\pi, 1)$ is an aspherical space.

Suppose $X$ and $K$ are connected CW complexes and suppose $K$ is aspherical. All spaces are assumed to be pointed and by "map" I will mean "pointed continuous function".

For any map $f\colon X \to K$ I claim it admits a factorization (up to homotopy) through $K(\pi_1(X), 1)$. Note that $K(\pi_1(X), 1)$ can be constructed so that there is a canonical isomorphism between its fundamental group and $\pi_1(X)$, so I will be implicitly using this identification even though strictly speaking they are not *equal*.

> Black Box: if $X$ and $K$ are connected CW complexes and $K$ is apsherical, then for any group homomorphism $\varphi \colon \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(K)$ there is a homotopically unique map $f\colon X \to K$ such that $\pi_1(f) = \varphi$.

(This result is typically proven using obstruction theory and I will omit a proof because it is standard.)

By the black box there is a homotopically unique map $i\colon X\to K(\pi_1(X), 1)$ inducing "the identity" on $\pi_1$, and a homotopically unique map $h\colon K(\pi_1(X),1) \to K$ which induces "$\pi_1(f)$". Then the composition

$$ h\circ i \colon X \to K(\pi_1(X), 1) \to K $$

induces the same homomorphism on $\pi_1$ as $f$, therefore by uniqueness $f \sim h \circ i$.

Now to deduce the result from the claim, if there is an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \in H_n(X)$ such that $H_n(f)(a) \neq 0\in H_n(K)$, then by homotopy-invariance of homology $H_n(h\circ i)(a) \neq 0$ so $H_n(i)(a)$ must be non-zero in $H_n(K(\pi_1(X), 1))$ as well, so we have the other direction of the equivalence.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that $M$ is connected, there is a unique, up to homotopy, map $f: M\to X=K(\pi,1)$ inducing the isomorphism $\pi_1(M, m)\to \pi_1(X, x)=\pi$. Then $f$ induces a homomorphism of homology groups
$$
H(f): H_*(M)\to H_*(X).
$$ 
This is the natural homomorphism appearing in Gromov's definition.

Comment: Here $\pi$ is the fundamental group of $M$?

Comment: @EduardoLonga: Right, $\pi_1(M,m)$ to be more precise. Unless you keep track of base-points, there is no canonical isomorphism of fundamental groups.

Comment: `Canonical' might be a better word than 'unique'. Although I'm not really sure how canonical the class actually is.

Comment: @Tyrone: Once you prescribe the isomorphism of fundamental groups, it becomes unique up to homotopy. But the nonvanishing of $H_n(f)$ is independent of the choices, so the issue becomes moot.

Comment: @MoisheKohan how do you see it is unique up to homotopy?

Comment: @EduardoLonga: You prove it the same way you construct the map: Given two maps $f_0, f_1$, build a homotopy between them, $M\times [0,1]\to X$, using induction on skeleta of $M\times [0,1]$. There are no obstructions to the extension to the next skeleton since $X$ is aspherical.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I think I understand what you mean, so you are fixing the particular homomorphism you have in mind as well as the isomorphism $\pi_1X\\cong \pi$? These choices were what I meant by `canonical', so I think we're in agreement.

Comment: @Tyrone: Right, I am fixing a particular isomorphism $\pi=\pi_1(M,m)\to \pi_1(X,x)$, otherwise, one has choices (up to homotopy, as many as $Aut(\pi)$). Of course, there is nothing like a "canonical" isomorphism here either, unless one uses some very special construction of $K(\pi,1)$.